# How to tail a file using Django?

Tags: jquery, python, django, tail

I would like to create a view where is possible to tail a file, like `tail -f` in Unix.
I know that some python modules already do that, like `tail`. For example, I can run this example in my `cmd` console:

```
import tail

def print_line(txt):
    ''' Prints received text '''
    print(txt)

t = tail.Tail('C:\\temp.txt')
t.register_callback(print_line)
t.follow(s=1)
```

But how can I use it in my `views.py` in python ? And keeping refreshing it, not the whole page, but my textarea only ? ?

```
def logs(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      #.. user inform which logs would like to tail
      # 'out' is the output from the tail function
      return render(request, 'logs.html', {'out': out})

  return render(request, 'logs.html')
```

My `.html` file:

```
<form action="/logs/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">

                <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="command" required>
                    <option value="">Choose a system log</option>
                    <option value="log1">LOG 1</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" value="tail" name="tail" id="tail">Tail?
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i> RUN!</button>

            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="30">{{ out }}</textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, thank you for you suggestion, but my project is hosted in Windows..

Comment: 1) use a "tail" solution on the server to get new lines; 2) use Websocket/SSE to push lines as they arrive to the client; 3) write custom Javascript to accept the lines and render them. Have fun!

Comment: @shavenwarthog, I thought about that this weekend, but I don't know  how to do the 3 step of yours: write custom Javascript to accept the lines and render them. Any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: this page as the JS part: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket